# could not install ipykernel. if pip is not available. please use the package

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

**I am working on a .ipynb file in visual studio code for the first time. I ran a small code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Set random seed to ensure reproducible runs
RSEED = 50
```

**but it is not running, this error pops up:**

could not install ipykernel. if pip is not available. please use the package...

Answer (score 2):

To use Jupyter to execute python code in VS Code, we need to have the following conditions:

1. Python is installed and available on the computer.

   After [downloading](https://www.python.org/) and installing python, enter "`python`" in the terminal that comes with the system to check whether it enters the python interactive window.

   [image]
2. Install the "python" extension and the "Jupyter" extension in VS Code.
3. Install Jupyter's kernel "`ipykernel`".(`pip install ipykernel` In the VS Code internal terminal.)

run:

[image]

Reference: [Jupyter in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support).

Comment: still same problem at 3. cmd says,"pip is not recognized as an internal or...".  i think it's pip's path issue. my system's windows is 8.1 64 bit.

Comment: @Muhammad Faheem Sajjad  -Since python comes with "pip", it is recommended that you reinstall python.

Comment: @Muhammad Faheem Sajjad  -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.